# XLT cross referencing between xml tags to decide what a class property should be added

Tags: html, css, xml, xslt

I have an xml file, that describes a conversation between Agent and Client. Both parties have a userId, that is assigned in the newParty tag.

Subsequent messages and notices, refer to this userId. I would like for when a message or a notice is processed, that a lookup is done by using the userId, to add the string "Agent" or "Client" to the class property of the generated HTML.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<chatTranscript startAt="2016-10-06T09:16:40Z" sessionId="0001GaBYC53D000K">
<newParty userId="007957F616780001" timeShift="1" visibility="ALL" eventId="1">
    <userInfo personId="" userNick="John Doe" userType="CLIENT" protocolType="FLEX" timeZoneOffset="120"/>
    <userData>
        <item key="GMSServiceId">5954d184-f89d-4f44-8c0f-a772d458b353</item>
        <item key="IdentifyCreateContact">3</item>
        <item key="MediaType">chat</item><item key="TimeZone">120</item>
        <item key="_data_id">139-e9826bf5-c5a4-40e5-a729-2cbdb4776a43</item>
        <item key="firstName">John</item><item key="first_name">John</item>
        <item key="lastName">Doe</item>
        <item key="last_name">Doe</item>
        <item key="location_lat">37.8197</item>
        <item key="location_long">-122.4786</item>
        <item key="userDisplayName">John Doe</item>
    </userData>
</newParty>

<newParty userId="0079581AF56C0025" timeShift="20" visibility="ALL" eventId="2">
    <userInfo personId="1" userNick="allendei" userType="AGENT" protocolType="BASIC" timeZoneOffset="120"/>
</newParty>

<message userId="007957F616780001" timeShift="25" visibility="ALL" eventId="3">
    <msgText msgType="text" treatAs="NORMAL">This is message one.</msgText>
</message>

<message userId="0079581AF56C0025" timeShift="35" visibility="ALL" eventId="4">
    <msgText msgType="text" treatAs="NORMAL">This is message two.</msgText>
</message>

<notice userId="0079581AF56C0025" timeShift="40" visibility="ALL" eventId="5">
        <noticeText noticeType="USER_CUSTOM">This is notice one.</noticeText>
</notice>

<notice userId="007957F616780001" timeShift="58" visibility="ALL" eventId="6">
    <noticeText noticeType="USER_CUSTOM">This is notice two.</noticeText>
</notice>

<partyLeft userId="007957F616780001" timeShift="90" visibility="ALL" eventId="4" askerId="007957F616780001">
    <reason code="3">left due to disconnect</reason>
</partyLeft>
```

... and my xlt is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<xsl:template match="/chatTranscript">
  <html>
    <header><xsl:value-of select="@sessionId" /></header>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="newParty" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="message/msgText" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="notice/noticeText" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="partyLeft/reason" />
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="newParty[userInfo/@userType='CLIENT']">
  <div class="Client" id="{@userId}">
    <label>Client: <xsl:value-of select="userInfo/@userNick" /></label>
  </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="newParty[userInfo/@userType='AGENT']">
  <div class="Client" id="{@userId}">
    <label>Agent: <xsl:value-of select="userInfo/@userNick" /></label>
  </div>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="msgText">
  <div class="Messages" id="{../@eventId}">
    <label>Message: <xsl:value-of select="text()" /></label>
  </div>
</xsl:template>   

<xsl:template match="noticeText">
  <div class="Notices" id="{../@eventId}">
    <label>Notice: <xsl:value-of select="text()" /></label>
  </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="reason">
  <div class="Notices" id="{../@eventId}">
    <label>Reason: <xsl:value-of select="text()" /></label>
  </div>
</xsl:template>
```

the desired output is as follows - where the class property(Agent or Client) of Messages and Notices are lookup up via the userID in the newParties at the top.

```
<html>
<header>0001GaBYC53D000K</header>
<div class="Client" id="007957F616780001"><label>Client: John Doe</label></div>
<div class="Client" id="0079581AF56C0025"><label>Agent: allendei</label></div>
<div class="Messages,Client" id="3"><label>Message: This is message one.</label></div>
<div class="Messages,Agent" id="4"><label>Message: This is message two.</label></div>
<div class="Notices,Agent" id="5"><label>Notice: This is notice one.</label></div>
<div class="Notices,Client" id="6"><label>Notice: This is notice two.</label></div>
<div class="Notices,Client" id="4"><label>Reason: left due to disconnect</label></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSLT has a built-in mechanism for performing lookups. Start by defining a **[key](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#key)** as:

```
<xsl:key name="party" match="newParty" use="@userId" />
```

then use it as shown in the following example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="party" match="newParty" use="@userId" />

<xsl:template match="/chatTranscript">
    <html>
        <header>
            <xsl:value-of select="@sessionId" />
        </header>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="newParty[userInfo/@userType='CLIENT']">
    <div class="Client" id="{@userId}">
        <label>Client: <xsl:value-of select="userInfo/@userNick" /></label>
      </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="newParty[userInfo/@userType='AGENT']">
    <div class="Client" id="{@userId}">
        <label>Agent: <xsl:value-of select="userInfo/@userNick" /></label>
    </div>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="message">
    <xsl:variable name="party-class">
        <xsl:call-template name="lookup-class"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <div class="Messages,{$party-class}" id="{@eventId}">
        <label>Message: <xsl:value-of select="msgText" /></label>
    </div>
</xsl:template>   

<xsl:template match="notice">
    <xsl:variable name="party-class">
        <xsl:call-template name="lookup-class"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <div class="Notices,{$party-class}" id="{@eventId}">
        <label>Notice: <xsl:value-of select="noticeText" /></label>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="partyLeft">
    <xsl:variable name="party-class">
        <xsl:call-template name="lookup-class"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <div class="Notices,{$party-class}" id="{@eventId}">
        <label>Reason: <xsl:value-of select="reason" /></label>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="lookup-class">
    <xsl:variable name="party-type" select="key('party', @userId)/userInfo/@userType" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$party-type='CLIENT'">Client</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$party-type='AGENT'">Agent</xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Note that the output is not valid HTML.

Comment: thank you for your answer - it works like I intend. One question regarding the implementation though - I noticed that the order of the elements being printed out was wrong before, but now with your solution it is in order. I was planning to do a sort on the EventId, but with this solution of your it does not seems necessary. Could you please explain why?

Comment: I don't know what the "correct" order is. The above follows the order of the source document.

Comment: before it was giving me all the messages processed in one go, then the notices etc. Don't worry about it. I will give it more research as to how the elements are meant to be processed into a tree-like structure.

Comment: That's because you had a separate `xsl:apply-templates` instruction for each.

Comment: OK I got it. Thank you.